GNOME control center will not launch due to undefined symbol FT_Get_Color_Glyph_Paint
If I try to launch gnome-control-center, I get:
$ gnome-control-center 
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Color_Glyph_Paint

It is hard to say what caused this. The control center was working earlier today. The only thing I remember doing was installing a game in a Wine prefix.
Ubuntu 22.04

Further information: FT_Get_Color_Glyph_Paint is a freetype call and
$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 | grep free
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007d195c9b6000)


This was my process in fixing this.
First, we have to understand the error.
[program name]: symbol lookup error: [shared object].so: undefined symbol: [some symbol]

This type of error means that in the process of running [program name], the program loaded the shared object [shared object]. Some code inside that shared object then tried to load the symbol [some symbol] and couldn't find it. The error does not mean that [program name] tried to find [some symbol] inside [shared object] and couldn't find it.
So libwebkit2gtk is trying to find some symbol called FT_Get_Color_Glyph_Paint. Some googling will reveal this is a freetype call. Okay, so let's find out in which .so file libwebkit2gtk is looking for freetype:
$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 | grep free
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007d195c9b6000)

This command will show all the .so files that libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 wants to load things from, and the grep will find freetype. So for some reason my libwebkit2gtk wants to get freetype from some binary in /usr/local/. As an experiment, let's try deleting or renaming that file:
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so.6 /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so.6.backup

And now run ldd again:
$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 | grep freetype
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007ce3098ee000)

So it is now getting freetype from somewhere else, in /lib/, which seems better. And indeed, gnome-control-center now runs.
This is not a great fix because ideally I would like to understand where the binary in /usr/local came from and come up with a better solution (actually ideally I would prefer if my system not break in random ways when some unrelated program or action puts a library in /usr/local/, but that's another story...), but it will do for now.
